# Apache2 Server over IPv6 using Teredo

Tags: networking, server, apache2, firewall

I'm trying to set up an Apache server on my Ubuntu 16.04 system that I can use to serve a basic HTML file with some system status information that I can access from my phone.

My phone is on IPv6 and I want to get around the NAT, so I set up Teredo tunneling from IPv4 to IPv6 on my Ubuntu 16.04 computer and I can ping my computer from outside my LAN using http://www.subnetonline.com/pages/ipv6-network-tools/online-ipv6-ping.php.  I tried it both from my computer and phone and it works both ways.

Apache2 also works and I can get the default page in the browser of my desktop computer using http://[::1] and the full IPv6 address.  I also updated ufw to allow http traffic through:

> $ sudo ufw status
>
> Status: active
>
> To                         Action      From
>
> --                         ------      ----
>
> 22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
>   80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
>   22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
>   80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

However, I still can't access the Apache default page from the browser on my phone.  Is there anything else I can check to figure out why my computer is responding to external pings, but not HTTP requests?

Comment: Are you sure it is the computer and not your router replying to the pings?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an IPv4 router and the pings show up when I do a "tcpdump -i teredo"

Answer (score 0):

Running a server on a Teredo address is usually a bad idea because the clients will experience unreliable connectivity to your server.

Your scenario is a bit special in that you plan for your phone to be the only client, and as such you might not have the same reliability requirements as the typical server. You just need to keep the gotchas in mind.

The most common reason for Teredo to break is lack of Teredo relays. Another way you can easily break Teredo is by filtering ICMPv6 packets.

**Things to look out for**

- Find the IPv6 address of your phone and use one of the many ping test sites on the net to try pinging that address. If your phone does not respond to ping it will never be able to communicate with a server hosted on a Teredo address.
- Find out which Teredo relay is being used by the ISP your phone connects to. If that ISP does not have their own Teredo relays you may be relying on third party relays which means no guarantees about reliability and no simple way to report problems.
- Decide how your phone will find your server. Teredo is designed to provide a device with a single dynamic IPv6 address. A static address is not possible with an unmodified Teredo client and Teredo server. So you need to find a way for the phone to know the IPv6 address of your server as it changes. One possibility is to use a dynamic DNS provider with IPv6 support.